# Asp.Net Entity Framework textbox to database

Tags: sql, asp.net, visual-studio

New to this.

I have a database, one table "Logins":

```
FirstName, LastName, Birthdate, Email
```

I am using VS2015 and I am using Entity Framework 6 and have my database loaded in through there.  I have text boxes and I want the data entered in them to insert into the table "Logins" when submit is clicked.

I've been looking online and watching videos an I just seem to be getting more confused.  How do I do this?

This is what I have on the back end code (the front just has the textboxes and submit button):

```
 protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        using (LoginData2Entities lg = new LoginData2Entities())
        {

            DateTime birthdate = DateTime.Parse(tbBirth.Text);

            Logins l = new Logins();
            l.FirstName = tbFirstName.Text;
            l.LastName = tbLastName.Text;
            l.Birthdate = birthdate;
            l.Email= tbEmail.Text;


            lg.SaveChanges();


        }
```

Nothing is saving to the database.  How do I fix this?

Comment: missing `lg.Logins.Add(l)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not adding the Login object l with your LoginData2Entities object so there is nothing to save into the database.. add this in your code.

```
lg.Logins.Add(l);
```

it will look like this..

```
using (LoginData2Entities lg = new LoginData2Entities())
        {

            DateTime birthdate = DateTime.Parse(tbBirth.Text);

            Logins l = new Logins();
            l.FirstName = tbFirstName.Text;
            l.LastName = tbLastName.Text;
            l.Birthdate = birthdate;
            l.Email= tbEmail.Text;
            lg.Logins.Add(l);
            lg.SaveChanges();

        }
```

Comment: AH, that was it!  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you are not adding the object to database before performing savechanges..

```
 using (LoginData2Entities lg = new LoginData2Entities())
        {

            DateTime birthdate = DateTime.Parse(tbBirth.Text);
            Logins l = new Logins();
            l.FirstName = tbFirstName.Text;
            l.LastName = tbLastName.Text;
            l.Birthdate = birthdate;
            l.Email= tbEmail.Text;
            lg.Logins.Add(l); //add the object 
            lg.SaveChanges();
        }
```